# How to convert column names to all uppercase in Google Bigquery? (SQL) (Images included)

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to clarify that I am not looking to covert the data within a column to upper case, rather I would like the column names to be in upper case. I know I can do this manually by selecting every column and setting it as uppercase, but I have a lot of columns and want to scale it across my entire table. See image below. I want those columns to be in upper case characters

[image]

Comment: ctrl-u 1000 esc u, to make the create database script all upper case. (At least the 1000 words, repeat if needed.)

Comment: Thank you, may you share an example please? I am not quite sure I am following.

Comment: Is it your own database, then re-create it - this time in upper case. And you should always have a script ready to do this, in case of emergency. Just alter that script.

Comment: Ahh but that would require to be manually typed ?

Comment: A nice editor can fix the upper case.

Comment: Column names in BigQuery tables are case insensitive! - so what the point?? please clarify - I feel your real use-case can be addressed differently than just renaming columns  in the table. Are you actually looking for the uppercase fields in the query output/result? But still - why? knowing your use-case will help us better help you

Answer (score 2):

You can build that line with this:

```
SELECT
 string_agg(concat(column_name,' as ', upper(column_name)), ',') as column_string
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
```

this returns

`geo_id as GEO_ID,zipcode as ZIPCODE,population as POPULATION,minimum_age as MINIMUM_AGE,maximum_age as MAXIMUM_AGE,gender as GENDER`